# Page Jumps on android browser on text input

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile

I have a login page which is giving a lot of pain. Whenever try to input text, the page jumps badly. I have tried turning off -webkit-backface-visibility. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by 3d transforms being applied to the input element or a parent of the input element.

For example, I had added transforms to my elements to force GPU acceleration to make CSS transitions faster using the code:

```
.GPUAccel, .GPUAccel div:not(.noGPUAccel) {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Which inadvertently caused some test phones (for example, the LG optimus slider), to bounce around when typing characters into the input fields.

Removing the GPU Acceleration, or transformations, from the parent element, solved this issue.

This seems to be a rather elusive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the browser zooming? I had issues with the browser zooming on inputs/dialogs etc... Try setting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` in your `<head/>`

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. The backface-visibility was causing the problem. @BPM: I used Jquery Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use of jq-touch? I faced this issue when using the same. I solved it by playing around with the position attribute in the css, changed it to be absolute.

Comment: Can you give more detail, I've tried setting the page, form and other elements to absolute. I still get this wacky scrolling on form inputs. Same is true for the jqtouch forms demo.